# How to implement a type guard on the return type of a callback in typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-generics

I have a generic function I'm trying to write and I'm learning a lot from this experience.

Here it is so far:

```js
/**                                                                        
 * Generic helper that maps an object (hash), while keeping its structure  
 * @param cb callback which performs mapping. It will always receive two arguments (key and
 * value), and it can either return:                                       
 * 1. just the value, in which case keys are unchanged, or                 
 * 2. an array of type [string, T], allowing keys to be modified as well.  
 */
function mapObject<T>(
    obj: Record<string, T>,
    cb: ((k: string, v: T) => [string, T]) | ((k: string, v: T) => T)
) {
    const result: Record<string, T> = {};
    Object.keys(obj).forEach((k) => {
        const item = cb(k, obj[k]);
        if (item instanceof Array) {
            result[item[0]] = item[1];
        } else {
            result[k] = item;
        }
    });
    return result;
};

console.log(mapObject({ 'a': 1, 'b': 3, 'c': 5 }, (n, e) => ['mapped' + n, e * e]));
console.log(mapObject({ 'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3 }, (_n, e) => e * e));
```

This works.

```
[LOG]: {
  "mappeda": 1,
  "mappedb": 9,
  "mappedc": 25
} 
[LOG]: {
  "a": 1,
  "b": 4,
  "c": 9
}
```

Hooray! However, peeking at the generated javascript, it's not to my liking:

```js
function mapObject(obj, cb) {
    const result = {};
    Object.keys(obj).forEach((k) => {
        const item = cb(k, obj[k]);
        if (item instanceof Array) {
            result[item[0]] = item[1];
        }
        else {
            result[k] = item;
        }
    });
    return result;
}
```

I'm doing a per-element check inside the loop. My question is, how can I use typescript type machinery to avoid this and let me implement the type guard where I want to be (outside the loop)?

`instanceof` is not powerful enough here.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that just hammering away with a type predicate does work a treat:

```js
type ObjectKVMapper<T> = (k: string, v: T) => [string, T];
type ObjectVMapper<T> = (k: string, v: T) => T;
type ObjectMapper<T> = ObjectKVMapper<T> | ObjectVMapper<T>;

function isOKVM<T>(x: ObjectMapper<T>): x is ObjectKVMapper<T> {
    return x('', '' as any) instanceof Array;
}

function mapObject2<T>(
    obj: Record<string, T>,
    cb: ObjectMapper<T>
) {
    const result: Record<string, T> = {};
    if (isOKVM(cb)) {
        Object.keys(obj).forEach(k => {
            const item = cb(k, obj[k]);
            result[item[0]] = item[1];
        });
    } else {
        Object.keys(obj).forEach(k => result[k] = cb(k, obj[k]));
    }
    return result;
};

console.log(mapObject2({ 'a': 1, 'b': 3, 'c': 5 }, (n, e) => ['mapped' + n, e * e]));
console.log(mapObject2({ 'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3 }, (_n, e) => e * e));
```

The generated js:

```js
function isOVM(x) {
    return x('', '') instanceof Array;
}
function mapObject2(obj, cb) {
    const result = {};
    if (isOVM(cb)) {
        Object.keys(obj).forEach(k => {
            const item = cb(k, obj[k]);
            result[item[0]] = item[1];
        });
    }
    else {
        Object.keys(obj).forEach(k => result[k] = cb(k, obj[k]));
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: I realize after posting that I made this utility overly constrained, it should return type any, rather than T. I think the general gist of it all holds though.